# When i am using multidex in android Application start taking more time

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

i am developing application from 4.2 to 6.0 but multidex enable is so when app is starting first at that time getting with blank white screen for few time like 4 to 5 seconds . how to resolve  that issue

Comment: InstantRun is disabled?

Comment: R.Zagorski Yes instant run is disable

Comment: This delay is removed in release version

Comment: @RomanSamoylenko Thanks